# OpenDJ Password Re-Use attribute

Tags: opendj, password-policy

Trying to implement a password policy to prevent Password Re-Use but am unable to do it with password-history-count.

Is there another attribute i should be using to achieve this? We are running OpenDJ 2.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the password-history-count in the Password Policy that is applied to the users is the way to verify that new passwords are not reusing existing passwords.

It's working fine out of the box, with all versions of OpenDJ.

```
$ ldappasswordmodify -p 1389  -D uid=user.0,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com -w password -n password
The LDAP password modify operation failed: 19 (Constraint Violation)
Additional Information:  The provided new password was already contained in
the password history
```

Have you tried to change the Default Password Policy, or to define a new password policy to prevent reuse ?